# Why is my input not creating a folder?

Tags: scripting, solaris

I cannot figure out why my script is not creating a folder from my input.

Heres my code ...

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "Please enter a foldername to store archives in"
 read $2
 echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
 mkdir $2
 echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a wrong variable to store the directory name $2 is the second parameter given to your script when you execute it (it could be empty if no second parameter). However i never tested but maybe it could work. The main problem is that for a the read function, you provide the variable without a '$'.

Try to declare a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
foldername=""
echo "Please enter a foldername to store archives in"
read foldername
echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
mkdir $foldername
echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
```